# Can you use the same application package name in different market account?

Tags: android, google-play

I already have a google developer account, but I would like to make a brand new google developer account for an app I'm about to publish.

Can I use the same package name in both market accounts?  For example, if I have Google developer account number 1, with apps that share the package name (eg com.myawesomeapps.app1, com.myawesomeapps.app2)....can I make a brand new goodle developer account and use the same package name (ie com.myawesomeapps.ap3)?

I'm only asking because I'd like to have a different google developer account for this new app but keep my package name, and I don't want to pay the publisher fee if this is not possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must use a different package name for each app -- and you can **never** change the package name. If you ever use a different package name you will be releasing a completely separate app.

As far as I know there is nothing stopping you from using the same *substring* in different package names within the market, though.

Since com.myawesomeapps.ap3 is different from com.myawesomeapps.ap2, that should be fine.

Note that your package name must be universally unique (nothing that anyone else will ever use), and can **never** be changed. The closest you can get to changing the package name is to abandon one app completely and start a new one with a new package name, but there will be no "link" between them in the market other than what you say in your description text.

This blog post explains package names a bit more; it's a bit old but AFAIK it's still accurate: http://blog.javia.org/android-package-name/

Answer (score 4):

No, its not possible to do so when publishing in Android Market. We cannot use the same package name to submit another app either from the same account or from any other account. The package name is unique for each application and can also not be transferred from one user to another.

Comment: Re-read his post -- he's talking about using a different package name with a common substring, not reusing the same package name for a different app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a different package name for the new App. Google Play Store identifies the App by the package name. I had a similar requirement, so for the new App, I used a different package name just for the App Package Name and Launcher Activity. Rest of app (Rest of the Activities, Fragments, and whole other app code) remained in the old package name, and the new App works just fine.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can, but you have to change in android studio in the gradle file, the aplicationId

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.example.app1'
}
```

To

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.example.app2'
}
```

Then you can upload it into google play

Comment: What you are doing here is changing the package name.  This is exactly what the question is asking to avoid.

Comment: It will change the package name, but you don't have to do it in all your java code. That was what I tried to say. Thanks for your time!